# Alterning three or more colors for cicles turtle python

Tags: python

I'm working with turtle python and I'm trying to do something like that:

[image]

I did the code for two colors, that is basically easy. The problem is that I don't know how to define the alternating color for three or more. Here is my code:

```
imp = 0
while imp != 5:
    wn = turtle.Screen()
    Cicle = turtle.Turtle()
    Cicle.speed(30)
    print("1) Use just one color (Default orange)")
    print("2) Use two colors (Default: red and blue)")
    print("3) Use three colors (Default: red, blue and orange)")
    print("4) Use four colors (Default: red, blue, yellow, black)")
    print("5) If you want to exit")
    imp = eval(input("Make your choice: "))
    number = eval(input("How many cycles do you want to draw? "))
    radius= eval(input("Define the radius: "))


    if imp == 1:           
        for x in range(number):
            Cicle.color("orange")
            Cicle.circle(radius)
            Cicle.right(int(360/number))

    if imp == 2:
        wn = turtle.Screen()
        Cicle = turtle.Turtle()
        Cicle.speed(15)
        for x in range(number):
            if x % 2 == 0:
                Cicle.color("blue")
            else:
                Cicle.color("red")
            Cicle.circle(radius)
            Cicle.right(int(360/number))

    if imp == 3:
        wn = turtle.Screen()
        Cicle = turtle.Turtle()
        Cicle.speed(15)

        for x in range(number):

            if x:
                Cicle.color("red")
            if x + 1:
                Cicle.color("blue")
            if x + 2:
                Cicle.color("orange")
            Cicle.circle(radius)
            Cicle.right(int(360/number))
```

Are you able to help me?

Comment: P.S: I know that the if statement does not have sense. It was just a trying

Comment: I'm not *entirely* sure I understand your question, but it sounds to me that creating an (infitely looping) [`cycle()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) of your three colors could work for you. For example: `colors = cycle(['red', 'green', 'blue'])` and you'd then pull out the next color when you need it by doing `color = colors.next()`.

Comment: aaah. Yeah. Maybe it will work. I did not know the existence of next function also in python. I'll try

Comment: To keep doing it the way you've started, think about this: what value does `x % 2` have in the `else` case? Where does that `2` come from? How could that logic be extended to `3` colours?

Comment: An alternative approach would be to just use the modulo operator like you did in your code for two colors, but do `x % 3` instead, and use the result to index a list of colors: `colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue']; color = colors[x % 3]`

Comment: Yeah I tried to use the modulo operation. But the problem is: in case of % 2 I can say x % 2 == 0 or x % 2 != 0. What I have to use in case of 3??

Comment: Exactly @jonrsharpe. In case of two colors I can alternate between odd and even number of cycles. But what in case of three colors?

Comment: @pp94 you would use the result of the modulo operation as an index for a list. You've got three colors, if you put those in a list it will have the indexes `0`, `1` and `2`. If you do `anything % 3`, the result will always be `0`, `1` or `2`. So you can use that result as the index for your list: `colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue']; idx = x % 3; color = colors[idx]`

Comment: I'll try. In advance, why I had -1 in my question?

Comment: Think about it, then try `for x in range(6): print(x, x % 3)`. Also, don't use `eval`.

Comment: Oh Damn. Sorry @LukasGraf I didn't see your comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using a list of colors and storing some default colors that the user can overwrite.

Then you can use the same principle as in your code for two colors: Using the **modulo** operation to select a color. When you have the colors in a list, you can then use the result of the modulo operation as the **index** for the list:

```
if imp == 3:
    wn = turtle.Screen()
    Cicle = turtle.Turtle()
    Cicle.speed(15)
    colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue']
    for x in range(number):
        c = colors[x % 3]
        Cicle.color(c)
        Cicle.circle(radius)
        Cicle.right(int(360/number))
```